# what is Bonjour?

Tags: iphone, bonjour, conceptual

I was watching wwdc videos this afternoon and I heard the word Bonjour .

So I just want to know what is Bonjour in Apple .

This is just to clear the concept .

Thanks

Comment: A great tutorial on bonjour and networking :http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/

Comment: I also found we can use bounjour services by NSNetServie from the above turorial .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In computing, Bonjour (formerly Rendezvous[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software))) is Apple Inc.'s trade name for its implementation of Zeroconf, a service discovery protocol. **Bonjour locates devices such as printers, other computers, and the services that those devices offer on a local network using multicast Domain Name System service records**.

- [More about Bonjour at Wikipedia ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software))
- [Apple's Bonjour FAQ](http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/faq.html)

Macs (OSX 10.4+) come installed with `dns-ds`, which is a

```
dns-sd -- Multicast DNS (mDNS) & DNS Service Discovery (DNS-SD) Test Tool
```

---

> Zero configuration networking (zeroconf), is a set of techniques that automatically creates a usable Internet Protocol (IP) network without manual operator intervention or special configuration servers.
>   Zero configuration networking allows inexpert users to connect computers, networked printers, and other network devices and expect a functioning network to be established automatically. Without zeroconf, a user must either set up special services, like Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) and Domain Name System services (DNS), or set up each computer's network settings manually, which may be difficult or impossible for non-technical or novice users.

[More about zeroconf ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf)

Comment: Just one question what the command do ?Sorry for asking this but I don't have my mac right now ?